# Graph, Definition of strongly connected component (SCC)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, connected-components

According to the definition of strongly connected component T in a directed graph G(V, E), it says that for each u,v vertices in T then there is a path connecting them together (in both direction)

My question is, suppose I found a strongly connected component, does that mean the path can always include vertices from within T and not V\T?

If not can I see a contradiction example?

Answer (score 1):

If by "the path" you mean *every* path from **u** to **v** or vice-versa, then yes, it does.

If a vertex **w** is on a path from **u** to **v**, then of course it can reach **v**.  Also, **v** can at least reach **w** through **u**.

**w** can reach *everything* reachable by both **v** and **u** -- **v**, **u**, and **w** can all reach exactly the *same* set of vertices.

They are in the same SCC.

Perhaps the easiest way to understand the definition of an SCC is like this:  If you remove all edges that aren't in cycles, then each remaining connected component is a *strongly* connected component.  Each vertex in an SCC can reach all the other ones.